# Django : Serializer validation prevents my code from updating an existing object

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project that get some user data and store them in a database.
I want my function to handle both `Create` and `Update` with the same method, so I created a view that inherit from `UpdateAPIView`

```
class UserList(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = RawUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RawUserSerializer
    
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        raw_user_serializer: RawUserSerializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        raw_user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)  # Fail when user already exists
        raw_user: RawUser = RawUser(**raw_user_serializer.validated_data)

        // Some custom computing

        # Create or update raw_user
        self.perform_update(raw_user_serializer)

        return JsonResponse({'user_id':raw_user.id}, status = 201) 

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = RawUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RawUserSerializer
```

I think that the use of a `UpdateAPIView` and the function `perform_update()` is good. It works well when the user doesn't exist already, but when I try to create a new user with the same primary key, I get : `Bad Request: /api/profiling/users/`, with the following response :

```
{
    "id": [
        "raw user with this id already exists."
    ]
}
```

It look like it fails on `raw_user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` instruction. How can I solve my issue ? (while keeping the validation of my object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serializer thinks you want to *create* a new object. You should pass the instance you want to (completely) update:

```
class UserList(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = RawUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RawUserSerializer

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        raw_user_serializer: RawUserSerializer = self.get_serializer(
            instance, data=request.data, partial=False
        )
        raw_user_serializer.is_valid(
            raise_exception=True
        )  # Fail when user already exists
        raw_user = raw_user_serializer.update(self.instance, validated_data)

        # some computing…

        self.perform_update(raw_user_serializer)

        return JsonResponse({'user_id': raw_user.id}, status=201)
```

Comment: Look like it is what I am looking for, but I don't manage to make it work. The `instance = self.get_object()` triggers the following error : `AssertionError: Expected view UserList to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.`

Comment: @Nakeuh: well you should make a PUT request, with the primary key of the path, so `PUT /foo/123`, not `PUT /foo`, what instance would it otherwise update?

Comment: Oh I see. I was using an `id` field from the body before. Thanks for your help !